# Update same table with calculated distance

Tags: postgresql, gps, postgis

This question is connected to [this:](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162416/calculate-road-distance-between-gps-points)

I can calculate distance with the new entries and insert into 4th column called distance. But now I need to make update query that uses ST_Distance to calculate progressive distance of existing GPS coordinates and store into distance column. Any idea how that can be achieved with my existing table design?

Answer (score 0):

In updating the values of existing rows you need to identify the row that comes before the current one, for each `device_id`. You can do this with a window function, partitioning the rows by `device_id` and ordering by `"timestamp"`, like so:

```
UPDATE my_table SET distance = cum_dist
FROM (
  SELECT dev, t, sum(d) OVER (PARTITION BY dev ORDER BY t) AS cum_dist
  FROM (
    SELECT mt.device_id AS dev, mt."timestamp" AS t,
           coalesce(ST_Distance(mt.GPS_location, lag(mt.GPS_location) OVER (PARTITION BY mt.device_id ORDER BY mt."timestamp")), 0.) AS d
    FROM my_table mt
  ) sub2
) sub
WHERE my_table.device_id = sub.dev
  AND my_table."timestamp" = sub.t;
```

A few words of explanation:

- The inner-most query `sub2` calculates the distance to the previous GPS location of the particular device. It uses the [`lag()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) to do so and the `coalesce()` function to make sure the first point in the series gets a distance of `0` instead of `NULL`.
- In the next query `sub` the cumulative distance is calculated, again using a window function, but this time with the well-known aggregate function `sum()`.
- The cumulative distance is then "updated into" the table by linking the query `sub` to the table using the `device_id` and `"timestamp"` columns.

As with all your updates, run the query first to see that it produces the correct results, then do the `UPDATE`.

Comment: I tried first with select clause but it missing a parenthesis, I added a parenthesis with the alias then it complains device_id doesn't exist. That's how alias looks like:  FROM "my_table" mt) s) sub

Comment: There was indeed a parenthesis and alias missing; see updated answer. The `device_id` should be no problem, but added table qualifiers just to make sure. Can you check again?